# Why Does Absolute Positioning Within Container Require Container to be Relative

Tags: css, positioning

It doesn't make sense to me.

If I want a div to be left:20px;top:20px from the container edge, I should be able to do something like position:absolute-within-parent;. Defining the positioning of a child should not require modification of the parent.

At least it seems more modular and decoupling that way. And as a programmer I've been taught to obsess with that.

Comment: `absolute` The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolute positioning is relative to something called the containing block. The containing block is the closest parent which has relative or absolute positioning (which may be the `body` element if nothing else could be found). This allows you to position an element relative to any one of its parents. `absolute-within-parent` would restrict you to only being able to absolutely position an element relative to its immediate parent, which isn't always what you need.

Comment: Ok I understand that. But shouldn't there be another property instead? For instance the container can have absolute-container:true;. This seems to be better than doing position:relative; because position:relative; conflicts with other properties in the sense that, if I ever need to make the container position:fixed; or position:absolute;, many things are broken. And if there is a absolute-container:true; properly, then nothing would be broken, which is a sign of good modular design.