# why, exactly, does absolute positioning inherit from a relative ancestor?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

This is a near duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725754/why-does-absolute-positioning-within-container-require-container-to-be-relative) but none of the answers there seem to really explain the rationale for this, which is what I'm really after.

I understand that absolutely positioned elements check up the parentage tree until they hit something with absolute, fixed, or relative positioning, then place themselves w/r/t to that element.

My question here is: what about relative positioning (as opposed to static, say) am I missing that would make this intuitive? It feels very arbitrary from my (utterly ignorant) viewpoint as a novice, so I'm keen for experts to help here. Does the act of declaring some element relative also make it X, where X is a logical thing for children to inherit their top-right corner from? Is a relatively-positioned element with no *top*, *right*, *bottom* or *left* set essentially a static element, or is it some fundamentally different animal at a deeper level?

Comment: It works that way because that's what the spec says. And the spec says so because it makes sense to have an element which resets the positioning which children can use to orient themselves on. And that element happens to be named `relative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) it makes sense:

> The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties. **These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block.** Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings. Also, though absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

I added emphasis to the appropriate section. Absolutely positioned elements are offset by their *containing block*

The [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block) specifies:

> In CSS 2.1, many box positions and sizes are calculated with respect to the edges of a rectangular box called a containing block. In general, generated boxes act as containing blocks for descendant boxes; we say that a box "establishes" the containing block for its descendants. The phrase "a box's containing block" means "the containing block in which the box lives," not the one it generates.

Relative Position establishes a new *containing block* therefore anything positioned absolutely within it is relative to the top left corner of it's containing block.

Unfortunately this doesn't exactly go into the reasoning "why"... for that you would have to dig up meeting notes of the W3C to find out (maybe). So the best answer we can give you is that "the spec says so."

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thanks! For me, the key bit in the spec that helped it make sense was "An element is said to be positioned if its 'position' property has a value other than 'static'. Positioned elements generate positioned boxes". So in some sense, everything apart from 'static' uses a special box logic that static, as the default, doesn't. I feel like that helps a lot!